# Calculate pixel from coordinates

Tags: coordinates, formula, pixel

Hello I have this image:

[image]

This image has 16 pixels. White is 0, pink 1... like in image. My problem is that I need to calculate number of pixel from coordinates. If I have coordinates x = 3 and y = 3, I need to get black pixel with number 15.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know how many pixels per row you have, you can simply use the next formula :

`(y * numberPerRow) + x`

Example using a 16 pixels images (4x4)

| x | y | calcul | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 3 * 4 + 3 | 15 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 * 4 + 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 * 4 + 1 | 9 |